# Not reading file from environment path

Tags: c++, file, system

I have create a project in which I am trying to generate a .txt file and then calling OS specific commands (I'm using unix so using `system()` function to trigger application) to open it in default application.

My code works perfect.

But the problem starts when I try to run my application after setting it in environment path. I am doing that for global visibility. File gets generated correctly by while opening the .txt using `system()` seems like it is trying to look at it at different directory.

I want to some how convey to the `system()` function to look at the specific location.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are actually just in a different working directory. Try showing the result of `getcwd`.

Comment: this is actually very close to what I want. i'm getting the entire path of my current address. but what I'm looking for is path where program is stored. Not the path from where I'm executing the program.